# Change of variable $x \rightarrow \frac{1}{x}$ and integration limits

Tags: integration

Suppose I have an integral

$$\int_{0}^{m}\dots dx$$

and I introduce a new variable $y = \frac{1}{x}$.
Supposed that I can correctly treat the integrand, this yields

$$\int_{\infty}^{1/m}\dots dy$$

Now compare this with

$$\int_{-0}^{m}\dots dx$$

which leads to
$$\int_{-\infty}^{1/m}\dots dy$$

Which one is valid and why?

Comment: Depends on whether $m$ is positive or negative.

Comment: A change of variables should be for a map from an interval to an interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux is that you need to treat the integral as $\displaystyle \int_{+0}^m dx$ as

$$\displaystyle \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_\epsilon^m dx$$

where $\epsilon \to 0^+$ indicates a limit "from above".

For the other integral, you would have $\displaystyle \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^-} \int_\epsilon^m dx$; since each interval $(\epsilon, m)$ then contains $0$ as an interior point, the substitution $y = \frac 1x$ is invalid.

Comment: Okay, the problem arose when calculating

$\int e^{\frac{m}{x}} x^{m} dx$.

I have opened up a separate topic for that: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215706/how-to-calculate-int-e-fracmx-xm-dx-for-positive-m
Thanks for your help!